# How can I resolve multiple versioned jar dependency on android?

Tags: java, android, jar, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I have an android project that has the following dependencies:

- jackson-core-asl-1.8.2.jar
- jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.2.jar

Now, I'm trying to use the following AWS android library jars for uploading files to S3

- aws-android-sdk-1.2.2-core.jar
- aws-android-sdk-1.2.2-s3.jar

The problem is aws-android-sdk-1.2.2-core.jar contains compiled class files for jackson-core-asl-1.8.7 (which is not backwards compatible with v1.8.2).

How can I resolve this dependency issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jarjar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) to change the package of jackson-core-asl-1.8.2.jar, or migrate your project to 1.8.7.